# Why a condition that contains a pointer always returns true?

Tags: c++, pointers

For example consider the following code. The pointer `p` points to the variable `a` that contains a nonzero value. Meaning, the condition should be true. So, if the program returns 1, I have no problem with that.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *p, a = 1;

    p = &a;

    if(p)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But for the following program the result is same too. Though the pointer this time points to a variable that contains 0. So, the condition should be false, but it is not.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *p, a = 0;

    p = &a;

    if(p)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, what I am missing? Why the condition is always returning true? I am assuming the pointer has nothing to do with the value that it points to. Rather it is evaluating the condition on the basis of something else and I want to know that particular reason.

Comment: `p` still points to a non-null address. You are not dereferencing the pointer

Comment: You are missing that `if (p)` is a shortcut for `if (p != nullptr)`. Maybe you meant to write `if (*p)` instead?

Comment: If you want to use/test the value at which `p` points, you have to _dereference_ the pointer: `if (*p) ...`.

Comment: To work with pointers you need to know the laws of pointers. A variable contains a value; a pointer is a value; a dereferenced pointer is a variable. In your example `p` and `a` are not aliases. `*p` and `a` are aliases.

Comment: Haha, two answers: one that answers the question you asked, and one that answers the question you wanted to ask :)

Comment: a pointer resolves to "true" if it points at something, even if that something is a variable set to zero/false. A pointer resolves to "false" if it's not pointing at anything (the pointer itself is null).

Comment: @nwp No, I did not wanted to write if `(*p)`. I have written what I have wanted. I just wanted to know why `if (p)` always returns true. I have got that answer now, that is `if (p)` is a shortcut for if `(p != nullptr)`.

Comment: @RubelHosen: Your question is full of statements of what the program *should* do; since all those statements are *false*, one can reasonably assume that you want a program that does what you falsely believe your program "should" do.

Comment: What you should do is (1) understand the laws of pointers, and (2) use equational reasoning in the context of those laws.  You said that `p = &a`, so from that you should conclude that `p == &a`, not that `p == a`. Similarly you should deduce from `p == &a` that `*p == *&a`, and since `*&a` is `a`, we deduce that `*p == a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (p)` does return true because `if (p)` is shortcut to `if (p != nullptr)`.

`p`contains the memory address of the variable `a`. In my machine that is `0x29fef8`. Since `nullptr` is equivalent to `0` and p is not `0` thus the condition `if (p != nullptr)` evaluates to true. Thus the condition always returns true.

Answer (score 6):

the null pointer is implicitly converted into boolean false while non-null pointers are converted into true. From the C++11 standard, section on Boolean Conversions:

A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type  bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to  false; any other value is converted to  true . A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type  bool ; the resulting value is  false

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
if(*p)
```

instead of

```
if(p)
```

`*p` dereferences pointer, yielding the value. `p` is just an object that holds the address of another variable.

Comment: maybe `if( p && *p )` is better

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in the condition of your if-statement:

```
if (p)
```

This is because in `p`, you store the value `&a`, and this is the address of the variable `a`, where the value is stored, **not** the variable itself.

The address of `a`, when I compiled your program and ran it, was `0x7fff0d9fd274`, and this is *not* zero. Any value in an if-statement's condition will always evaluate to `true` If that value is not zero. As a result, your condition is verified even if the value in `a` is changed, because your compiler does not **even** look at the value of `a`; it merely checks whether the address stored as a value in `p` is zero or not, which it isn't. Hence, your if-statement is always true, so the program terminates with returning a non-zero status always.

To fix this, you should use the `*p`instead of `p`. This syntax tells the compiler to get the value in the address stored by pointer `p`, which in the second program is, zero.

Changing your if-condition in your second program to:

```
if (*p)
```

Will terminate the program with a zero status, like you want it to.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In C, pointers are related to variables by two operators: **takeaddress**, represented by the ampersand character or **&**, and dereference, represented by the asterisk character, or *****.

1st of all, you should remember that a pointer holds the address of a memory position. So, your line
    p = &a;
is putting into the pointer variable `p` the address of the int variable `a`. That address is certainly not null, since a is an existing variable, with a real address.

This is why your test for `p` value will always hold true.

If you want to test the contents of the address hold by `p` -- that is, the value of `a`, you should dereference it. In other words, your code should be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *p, a = 0;

    p = &a;

    if(*p)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (p)` will always evaluate as true until `p` is not pointing to anything (address 0x). I think what you really want to do is `if (*p)` so you evaluate the value from the address `p` is pointing to. `*` is used to access the information from the address.

Remember that pointers retain addresses and not values, so `p = &a` and `*p = a`